# Angular8: How write a directive that converts a text input and applies it to a ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

Possibly a noob question, but I didn't found an answer.

I have an text input element, and I need to update the model with the input value. The property on the model is a number. Unfortunatly I can't use type="number" for the input element. The hostsystem/client has only a virtual keyboard and would show in this case a virtual numpad without '-', that doesn't allow negative numbers.

I would use a directive like `toNumber`

```
<input placeholder="allowed values are [-2..2]"
       [(ngModel)]="this.myModel.numberProperty" 
       type="text" 
       toNumber/>
```

Is that possible? How to do that? How can I get notifcations on input changes and how to access the ngModel?

Comment: You need to use validation. First thing is do decide on reactive vs template driven forms.

Comment: @AndreiTătar Can you point me to an example? I only found examples that validate but don't write to the ngModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using [(ngModel)] directive please use this way
(i added + on $event.target.value for number casting):

```
<input placeholder="allowed values are [-2..2]" type="text" 
[value]="this.myModel.numberProperty"
(input)="this.myModel.numberProperty= +$event.target.value"/>
```

or you can call for a function when input change:

```
<input placeholder="allowed values are [-2..2]" type="text" 
[value]="this.myModel.numberProperty"
(input)="onInputChange($event.target.value)"/>
```

and on your class:

```
onInputChange(value){
//do more stuff
this.myModel.numberProperty = +value;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't compile cause for `$event.target`  the property `value` is absent. Do I need to cast it to an other type?

Comment: try to send  for the function just the value, please see my change above